# Python Pandas DataFrame replace: strip string from trailing numbers

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a long DataFrame with index values like this:

```
| burger10 | ...

| pasta25  | ...

| milk     | ...

| yoghurt() | ...
```

I need to get rid of the trailing digits or parentheses. I am trying to use replace() with regex, but without success. Tried this:

```
energy.replace(to_replace='[0-9,\.,\(,\)]+', value='', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to escape `()` or use `,` in character class `[]`, just use them as literal, and if you mean *trailing*, you need the anchor `$` to match the end of string:

```
energy[0].str.replace("[0-9()]+$", "")

#0     burger
#1      pasta
#2       milk
#3    yoghurt
#Name: 0, dtype: object
```

---

If the strings are in the index, you can use `.index` to access, modify it and reassign it back to the data frame:

```
energy.index = energy.index.str.replace("[0-9()]+$", "")
```

Comment: I should add that my burger and pasta and milk represent the INDEX in the Pandas DataFrame. So, I am not sure how to apply your answer in a vectorized version for all items in the index of the DataFrame.

Comment: I updated the answer in case they are index. i.e. you can use `.index` to access them and make changes.